# Trouble with getting location on iphone 6.1 simulator

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode

I am very new to objective C and  Xcode. I was trying to find out the location of my iphone simulator and went through a tutorial on youtube. Following is the code.

```
#import "MainClassViewController.h"
#import <CoreLocation/CoreLocation.h>

@interface MainClassViewController () <CLLocationManagerDelegate>

@end

@implementation MainClassViewController
{
    CLLocationManager *manager;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    manager = [[CLLocationManager alloc]init];

}

- (IBAction)LocationButton:(id)sender 
{

    manager.delegate = self;
    manager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;

    [manager startUpdatingLocation];

}

#pragma mark CLLocationManagerDelegate Methods

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    NSLog(@"didFailWithError: %@", error);
    UIAlertView *errorAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc]
                           initWithTitle:@"Error" message:@"Failed to Get Your Location" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [errorAlert show];
}

-(void) locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation: (CLLocation *) oldLocation {

    NSLog(@"Location: %@", newLocation);
    CLLocation *currentLocation = newLocation;

    if(currentLocation != nil){
        _Lattitude.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.8f", currentLocation.coordinate.latitude];
        _Longitude.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.8f", currentLocation.coordinate.longitude];
    }
}
```

### @end

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface MainClassViewController : UIViewController

- (IBAction)LocationButton:(id)sender;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *Lattitude;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *Longitude;


@end
```

My questions are:
1. I am not sure why labels are not getting updated with location.
2. I want to learn more about debugging. Any suitable resources available. Please keep in mind I do not want learn all about debugging. Only what is required for the basics.

Comment: did you test in the simulator?

Comment: Yes. When I click on the button, it should change the text in the labels to latitude and longitude. Here is the code for header file as well:

Comment: so have you attached button's action and label outlets in inteface builder? For debugging at least NSLog should help you. Do you see any output in console?

Comment: Yes, I attached button's action and label outlets in interface builder.

Comment: There was no output in the console.